# I'd like to learn Struts.Is there any good web sites or books?

Tags: java, struts

I want learn it for abc.

And I'd like to know what's the difference between struts 1 and struts 2.

Answer (score 5):

Check this free book:

- [Jakarta Struts Live](http://www.theserverside.com/tt/books/sourcebeat/JakartaStrutsLive/index.tss)

Also [here](http://www.roseindia.net/struts/) you can find some good basic code examples.

For a Struts 1 vs. Struts 2 comparative, check [this](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=200).

Answer (score 2):

Personal opinion. [Jakarta Struts For Dummies](http://www.dummies.com/store/product/Jakarta-Struts-For-Dummies.productCd-0764559575.html) is really a piece of art from newbies.

It makes the shifting from jsp/servlet to struts so easy;)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't read the specific book, but I generally have good experience with Manning books, so I would recommend [Struts 2 in Action](http://www.manning.com/dbrown/).

Also, I would generally recommend to start directly from Struts 2 as it has some adantages over the 1.x versions. However, if you are using Eclipse, I am not aware of any plug-ins for Struts 2. This could be a problem for a new user. For Netbeans there is [this](https://nbstruts2support.dev.java.net/), but I haven't used it myself. For Struts 1.x there are mature plug-ins both for Eclipse and Netbeans.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend struts 2 also.

[The book Struts 2 in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/193398807X) I also recommend.

[The Struts 2 Apache web site](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/home.html) has a great reference and lots of tutorials, once you start moving away from the book. Use that site, and avoid RoseIndia if you can.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a bit of experience with Struts1 and Struts2. First off, Struts1 and 2 are different because Struts2 is not a direct evolution of Struts1 but rather it comes from another framework called [WebWork](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebWork). There are still a few similarities around the MVC pattern (Action classes, etc.). The validation and configuration XML files change. Struts2 uses the Dojo toolkit for many of it's JavaScript functionality. IMHO Struts2 has more features and improvements over Struts1, although it's probably not so widely spread in use as Struts1 is, at least not yet...

Answer (score 1):

the best abc tutorial as of now [Struts 2](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/)

Answer (score 0):

I personally recommend struts in action and as well if  u like to learn online these can be a good refference http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/struts-tutorials/